# JQuery or javascript not working on mobile view or on mobile device

Tags: jquery

I am new to javascript. I want to show one login form on click of anchor tag using javascript on browser mobile view or on mobile device.   I tried for 'touchstart click' but its not working, please help me.

```
//Login link 
<li class="main_nav_item"><a href="#" id="LoginLink">Login</a></li>

//Login form id and class
 <div class="container-fluid LoginFrm" style="margin-top:20px" 
id="LoginFrm">Login form code .......</div>


// Javascript
 $("#LoginLink").on('click', function ()  {
                ShowLoginForm();
            });
        function ShowLoginForm() {
                $(".LoginFrm").show();
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".LoginFrm").offset().top
                },
                    'slow');

            };
```

Currently it is working fine for desktop view, but it is not working on mobile view in browser or on mobile device. Please help me to solve this. 
I already used touchstart but it didnt work, Is there any extra plugin for touchstart????

Comment: Which mobile browser are you testing with? touchstart is not supported by opera and safari.

Comment: I am testing with Crome and Edge